# Why is Android force-stopping my app without any error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-studio-2.0

I am trying to run my Android app, it was working normally, but now when I try to run my app (`com.ulouder.ulouder`), I'm getting:

```
04-30 08:58:58.539 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder I/System.out: debugger has settled (1475)
04-30 08:58:58.544 4914-6591/system_process E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9fbdad40
04-30 08:58:58.729 4914-4942/system_process W/AppOps: Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
04-30 08:58:59.182 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder W/art: Verification of void com.ulouder.system.App.registerPushClasses() took 224.305ms
04-30 08:58:59.203 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
04-30 08:58:59.203 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
04-30 08:58:59.429 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder I/Fabric: Initializing Crashlytics 2.2.3.41
04-30 08:58:59.537 7683-7771/com.ulouder.ulouder W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10007
04-30 08:58:59.580 5519-5925/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/GCM: GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
04-30 08:59:00.163 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder W/art: Verification of void com.ulouder.activities.MainActivity.registerTabClickListeners() took 249.109ms
04-30 08:59:00.311 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-30 08:59:00.781 7683-7683/com.ulouder.ulouder D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-30 08:59:00.853 4883-4883/? I/Zygote: Process 7683 exited due to signal (11)
04-30 08:59:00.858 4914-5728/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.ulouder.ulouder (pid 7683) has died
```

There are no errors or anything else other than signal 11. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've restarted Android emulator and the problem went away. It's really unbelievable that Google's latest mobile OS is so crappy that it starts killing apps without appropriate errors. Anyway, the problem went away after an emulator restart.